# How to adjust the text direction in ant design Select with search field component in a Form item based on multiple languages?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, antd

I want to adjust the text direction in the search field automatically based on the language the user is typing in.
So for example, If he's typing in Arabic switch the text direction to `rtl` and if he's typing in English switch the text direction to `ltr`.

How can I achieve this while being able to read the selected value on submitting the form?

I tried to wrap the select component in a div and apply the `dir` attribute on it which worked fine but ended up making the selected value undefined.

Also, applying the `direction` css rule on the select component works but doesn't change automatically so if the user typed in English it will become and remain `ltr` even if he typed in Arabic afterwards

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-with-search-field-antd-5-6-0-forked-vnknw4?file=/demo.js:141-147).